# How to catch a client disconnection when sending a large file in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

I am sending a file in play application response. When the client downloads the file, i am cleaning the file from the local server. I am achieving this using below code:

```
val fileToServe = TemporaryFile(new File(fileName))
Ok.sendFile(fileToServe.file, onClose = () => { fileToServe.clean })
```

But when client disconnects the connection, the temporary file remains in the local server. But i want to handle this disconnection and clean up the
temporary file. I heard about **onDoneEnumerating()** but couldn't use it.

Can anyone point me out the easiest way to handle the disconnection and clean up the temporary file from local server?

Comment: Why not keeping track of each temporary resource affected to all connections? Such as with a connections pool?

Comment: please enlighten me with more details

Comment: This is something I used to do: whenever a connection is received, I store the connection in a global object where all the connections reside. Using dictionaries, I associate to each connection the resources they use or are allocated with. On disconnection it's easy to crawl for the used resources and take appropriate actions on those resources. As to 'how to detect' a disconnection, this I do not know with your framework. But that is basic, so I guess it's implemented ;-)

Comment: In play framework, i could not found anything to catch the disconnection. That's my actual query here.

Comment: The TemporaryFile in Play holds a reference to the actual file on the filesystem, and cleans it when it is garbage collected. You may try to research why the instance isn't destroyed by the GC. Keep in mind, that the garbage collector isn't guaranteed to run immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TemporaryFile is for when Play receives a data stream that has to be kept in a temporary file location, rather than you sending a file out.  It removes on finalization (pre 2.6) or on phantom file reference (2.6.x).

The easiest way to catch the disconnection is to call Files.deleteIfExists

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists-java.nio.file.Path-

in the onClose block.  If that doesn't seem to be working for some reason, you can use the temporary file reaper:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaFileUpload#Cleaning-up-temporary-files

that will clean out the temp files directory every so often.